UK GDPR, is it a breach to give one letter of a surname?
If someone gives the first letter of a surname to help jog the persons memory, so letter 'C'. No other information was given and the surname wasn't a common name. Have I broke GDPR by doing this? The surname was the person's name who I was speaking to & it was a previous married name. The person in question is in her 70's, & I felt she need help jogging her memory. My thinking is a bank will give a password hint eg name of first pet etc.

It's going to depend on a lot of things, such as how identifiable the person is and what the context was.

Was it information the person could have accessed in another way (for example by logging into their account or filing an SAR) or was it information only you had available? Did you have enough information to be able to authenticate the person you were talking to?

Hint:  If it's not a breach to pronounce someone's name in normal conversation then it's not a breach to say a letter of the alphabet.  I am not that familiar with GDPR, but it's rather absurd to believe that it might restrict ordinary conversations in the manner you describe.

Ann, your question could be improved with some context.  For example, were you, (or a hypothetical person...) acting in an official capacity as an agent of a data controller?  Did you, (or a hypothetical person...) know the individual?  Was it in person, or over the phone?  etc.  I think you are getting downvotes because at first reading this appears extremely naive.  If you could present a plausible scenario where a single letter of the alphabet might be considered a risk of disclosing personally identifying information to a third party you might be able to turn the tide here.

Depends on the context where this happens. GDPR requires the data controller (e.g. a company) to handle personal data of the data subject only in ways permitted by the GDPR, where handle may be any or all of store, modify, delete, or transmit.
One of the requirements of the GDPR is to have documented processes how data will be handled. It is not enough to do the right thing by happenstance or unthinking habit, the company must be aware what it is doing with the data, document that, and follow their own processes. Some of the documentation goes to national supervising authorities, some is used to write terms of service, privacy notices, and so on. It may well be that the same kind of processing is legal when the data subject agreed to it in properly written TOS, and illegal if there is no such agreement.
So as to your question, is there a policy on giving hints to jog a memory (or to help with password recovery, or whatever)? Did giving the hint break the policy? Then this might have been a GDPR violation. If the hint was according to company policy, it may still be that the company is breaking the GDPR, but that's no longer a problem for the individual employee, it is a problem for whoever signed off on the policy ...

So you are saying that it is a potential breach to share a person's information with that same person?

@MichaelHall the risk here is this might not be the person - at this point that hasn’t been verified.

@DaleM From the question:  "The surname was the person's name who I was speaking to & it was a previous married name"  (Acknowledging here that the question gives no additional context to assess risk of inadvertent disclosure to a third party...  i.e. was it over the phone, if so, were they verified by other means?!)

@MichaelHall I have the same surname as my wife but we have different “previous married names” - specifically, I’ve had the same surname all my life and she hasn’t - because patriarchy. It would be even worse if she had the same first name as her mother, which is not unheard of. What I’m saying is just because a person has the same name, it doesn’t mean they’re the same person.

@DaleM, I get that.  Again, I acknowledge that the details in the question are inadequate, so we are simply arguing presumptions. (See my latest comment to the OP.)

@MichaelHall, it is a "breach" not to follow the processes laid down to handle that data. If John Doe is standing in the office, and all the staff have known Mr. Doe for decades, they still may not be allowed to open the database and read Mr. Doe's entries to him if the process calls for crossing t's, dotting i's, checking his driver's license and logging all that in a form.

@o.m., Correct, presuming as you have that the OP is acting in a role as a data controller and has processes they are obligated to follow.  But you asked as many questions as I have in your final paragraph, so I guess it's all rather inconclusive and unsatisfactory unless we can get more detail...

@MichaelHall, as of now one close vote, -1, and no edit. I would not hold my breath.
